# Unpack/Repack ROM for SM-G930S (Samsung Galaxy S7)

Tags: samsung, rom

I want to unpack/repack the Samsung Galaxy S7 (SM-G930S) ROM. I downloaded the ROM from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TMVVyZTMYMcDA0-aVyMxLo5QvwOK4GWv/view). I use [simg2img](https://github.com/anestisb/android-simg2img) to unpack/repack on Ubuntu. I execute these commands:

```
lz4 system.img.lz4 system.img
pc@pc-virtual-machine:~$ ./android-simg2img/simg2img system.img system.raw.img
pc@pc-virtual-machine:~$ ./android-simg2img/img2simg system.raw.img system.new.img
```

Result: the file `system.img` loaded successfully, but the file `system.new.img` received a FAIL result when using Odin.

I noticed something unusual when comparing 2 files:

1. Check file info:

   ```
   pc@pc-virtual-machine:~$ file system*
   system.img:     Android sparse image, version: 1.0, Total of 1075200 4096-byte output blocks in 5625 input chunks.
   system.new.img: Android sparse image, version: 1.0, Total of 1075200 4096-byte output blocks in 3469 input chunks.
   system.raw.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4- 655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b (extents)
   ```
2. Check simg_dump.py:

   ```
   pc@pc-virtual-machine:~$ ./android-simg2img/simg_dump.py system.img
   simg_dump.py: system.img: The file header size was expected to be 28, but is 32.
   pc@pc-virtual-machine:~$ ./android-simg2img/simg_dump.py system.new.img
   system.new.img: Total of 1075200 4096-byte output blocks in 3469 input chunks.
   ```
3. Open with 7z:

   - File system.img

     > [image]
   - File system.new.img

     [image]

I used many tools: ext2simg, make_ext4fs to repack, but it didn't work.

How to unpack/repack the ROM?

Comment: issue [#28](https://github.com/anestisb/android-simg2img/issues/28) unresolved. you should add 1. + 2. there